# MySQL + PHP millions of rows, sorting the data from multiple queries. Memory Consumption

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

So I have 2 tables. One table has all the actual campaign_id information. 
The second table has the impression/statistic information on the campaign_id's

I have a table on the page (i use ajax, but that's besides the point). I want to "sort" a column, but all the rows are generated by the campaign_id table, I run all of the statistics for every campaign first, and then link them up to each row. then after all the info/data is up, it then sorts all of it. this uses a MASSIVE amount of memory and resources. **Is this efficient at all? is there a better solution to sorting huge amounts of data?**

```
// I have to increase memory because the sorting takes a lot of resource
ini_set('memory_limit','1028M');

// the column I want to sort
$sortcolumn = $this->input->post('sortcolumn');
// direction of the sort ASC/DESC
$sortby = $this->input->post('sortby');

// millions of impression data that is linked with campaign_id
$cdata= array();
$s  = "SELECT report_campaign_id,";
$s .= "SUM(report_imps) AS imps ";
$s .= "FROM Campaign_Impressions"; 
$s .= "GROUP BY report_campaign_id ";
$r = $this->Qcache->result($s,0,'campaignsql');
foreach($r as $c) {

  $cdata[$c->report_campaign_id]['imps'] = ($c->imps) ? $c->imps : 0;
}


// 500,000+ thousand campaigns
// I draw my table from these campaigns
$rows = array();
$s = "SELECT * FROM Campaigns ";
$r = $this->db->query($s)->result();
foreach($r as $c)
{
   $row= array();
   $row['campaign_id'] = $c->campaign_id;
   // other campaign info here...

   // campaign statistics here...
   $row['campaign_imps'] = $cdata[$c->campaign_id]['imps'];

   // table row
   $rows[] = $row;
}


// prepare the columns i want to sort
$sortc = array();
foreach($rows as $sortarray) {
  if (!isset($sortarray[ $sortcolumn ])) continue;
  $sortc[] = str_replace(array('$',','),'',$sortarray[ $sortcolumn ]);
}

// sort columns and direction 
array_multisort($sortc,(($sortby==='asc')?SORT_ASC:SORT_DESC),SORT_NATURAL,$rows);
```

As you can see, the "campaign_impressions" table is running data on "every" campaign, and doesn't seem so efficient, but more effective instead of running a query per row to know the data.

(I dont display all the campaigns, but I need to run every one of them to know the sorting of all)

Comment: JOIN Campaign_Impressions and Campaigns in a single query, allowing you to specify the ORDER BY clause in your query

Comment: No, not efficient: you're effectively copying the data from MySQL into PHP and working on it.  Better to push all the sorting and grouping into SQL, ideally paging or filtering in advance to limit the scope if appropriate.  Consider `JOIN` the impressions, `LIMIT` to provide pagination.  If you must do it in PHP, consider using `yield` to limit the effect of the intermediary map.

Comment: Define "massive". Normally sorting is inefficient if you don't have indexes, but is done in a temporary file to minimize memory impact. If your MySQL server is using excessive amounts of memory it's configured incorrectly.

Comment: @tadman im not sure the memory of the MySQL, the massive amount is the PHP itself doing the sorting. I'm more afraid of using the JOIN because it never seemed efficient enough or was always a bit slower. but sometimes I feel even with indexing, the DB gets to a certain size where it just becomes slow anyways. but maybe its configurations.

Comment: Well, yeah. If you're doing `SELECT * FROM giant_table_of_doom` your server is going to have a bad day. You're asking for *everything* and your application is going to try its damnedest to get it all. If you can do these operations inside the database itself, you'll send less data back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You should let MySQL do the job my using `order by`

if this still takes a lot of time on the MySQL side consider using sorted indexes on the columns